# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, c++11

I am writing a code for image processing using Opencv2.4 and using this header file in my program.

> ## include "opencv2/core.hpp"

After compiling the program this is the error

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I tried solving by adding the core folder in the header file

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

After doing this the number of errors increased as follows.

```
error C2653: 'ogl' : is not a class or namespace name   C:\OpenCV 4.0\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\OpenCV 4.0\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hp
```

Please help me to remove these errors. Thanks in advance

Comment: opencv4.0, wow, wish i had that ;)

Comment: now, seriously, which opencv version are you using ? "opencv2/core.hpp" is for 3.0, "opencv2/core/core.hpp" for 2.4

Comment: i am using opencv 4.0

Comment: You're not using 4.0 it doesn't exist

Comment: you must be living in the (very far) future ;)

Comment: yes you are right its opencv 2.4

Comment: add opencv to your path environment variable.

Comment: already done that its not working

Comment: can it be, that you're trying to use code intended for 3.0 with 2.4 ?

Comment: the code is written for 2.4 only